# Graphics card in guest system

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

My host system is Debian Jessie x64. I'm using VirtualBox 4.2+. Guest system is Win 7 x64. I enabled 3D acceleration. Also, installed guest drivers but any 3D app works really slow and Aero doesn't work either. What is wrong?

Comment: Under the setting for the virtual machine how much memory do dedicated to the video card? Upgrade to 4.3.6.  More video memory should help a little bit.

Comment: I upgraded to 4.3.6 and still the same problem, my card got 512MB and I want to set 256 for vm

Comment: Ignore what your video card has virtualization products substitute system RAM for video RAM.  My system has 4gb of video RAM and virtualbox still maxes at 128mb.

Comment: but even when I set 128, 3d apps run slow

Comment: That is correct all video features are emulated in software.  You can basically forget about 3d.